# Create Bloomberg Buyer and Seller Trade Tickets in a web application

Tags: bloomberg

I have a requirement where I need to develop a web application in which two application users negotiate with each and later after agreeing on terms they are to trade illiquid bonds via Bloomberg. For this I need to generate the BXT and SXT Trade Tickets through my application. The question really is that is this even possible without the Terminal?

A [white paper](http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/content/uploads/sites/2/2013/08/blpapi-request-response-use-case.pdf) on Bloomberg API's website says

> Other applications are possible, for example submissions of trade orders

But I am not able to find any reference or example how this can be achieved using [Bloomberg API](http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/) or any other service provided by Bloomberg.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if you are able to do this, by definition a web application is hosted on server x and interacted with from device y.  Bloomberg's entire business model is based around having a Bloomberg terminal on device y.

I'd recommend you look at other bond trading platforms not just Bloomberg, e.g. TradeWeb, MarketAxess or even the large brokers e.g. ICAP, Tullett who may have a more suitable API.

Comment: the current requirement is to integrate with Bloomberg, can this be achieved by letting the user download some sort of script on device y? It was previously possible but it seems that it is not any more [http://stackoverflow.com/a/26861427/1637965](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26861427/1637965)

Comment: I can't comment on DDE, in my previous job we used to use that to allow our traders to send commands from one desktop to another, but remember - if you're building a website you're going to be sandboxed within the browser so you are unlikely to be able to interact with the terminal at all.

Answer (score 0):

This might come a little bit late but you might want to have a look into Bloomberg's FIX API. I am working on a similar project and I have implemented this functionality in a web application that creates and sends Trade Tickets via FIX. You do not have to have a Bloomberg terminal installed. Your FIX session will connect directly to a Bloomberg FIX endpoint.

Bloomberg has a test environment for this. You have to contact one of their representatives and ask for a Beta FIX Session.

FIX is a publicly available protocol for exchanging financial information. A good starting point would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_Information_eXchange