# Bloomberg terminal and UFT tool

Tags: hp-uft, bloomberg

I am doing manual work on Bloomberg terminal on daily basis.
I am looking to automate manual work using `UFT` tool, but `UFT` is not able to recognize `Bloomberg` terminal and capture it's objects.
I tried using `TE` add-in in `UFT` but it is of no use.
Is it possible to automate Bloomberg Terminal with `UFT` tool?

Comment: Please include the relevant error messages within your question, Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use the appropriate wizard to define your own session specification to match the terminal setup

Comment: I am not sure on wizard. Is it in Bloomberg or UFT?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried macros and assigning them to buttons? Macros are short (or long) scripts of commands to run in the Bloomberg Terminal. Everything that you can do by typing into the command line - you can automate with a macro. To click a button or a menu, type their number and then `<go>`. You can even record macros and play them back.

Start by hitting `alt-b` in your Terminal to bring up the buttons and macros popup.

Edit: You can also use DDE to communicate with the Terminal, see (though it is deprecated, it should still work): [How to open a specific bloomberg terminal page programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644304/how-to-open-a-specific-bloomberg-terminal-page-programmatically)

Comment: I will look into it. I have a dataset with me, can I upload that dataset through macro? Hope you are not referring to excel add-in of Bloomberg.

Comment: This is not Excel api, it’s macros written inside the Terminal. Unfortunately, one limitation is that you can’t update them from an external source. You can’t have the macros behave differently according to some external data source.

Comment: I have one action to perform on Bloomberg terminal. Multiple data is there which is fed in Bloomberg with same action. Can we fetch data from Bloomberg terminal through macro?